# Python: PostgreSQL selected rows handle them in a dataclass like structure

Tags: python, postgresql, python-dataclasses

I'm looking for a SQL and not for a NOSQL package for Python and PostgreSQL.

I looked at psycopg2, it is for me too rudimentary, then pymongo, it is a NOSQL package, then SQLAlchemy -> perfect handling of the records, but NOSQL....

1. I'm new to Python, forgive me...
2. I like the new dataclass structure for Python!!
3. I'm from VB6, WinDev and PHP, looking for a good start for Python and PostgreSQL

I like a database structure like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class c_Country:
    CountryDescription: str = None

Countries = [c_Country("Austria")]
Countries += [c_Country("Germany")]

for Country in Countries[:]:
    print("Country: " + Country.CountryDescription)
```

Of course not adding "Countries" manually, instead having it from PostgreSQL database:

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "test",
                                  password = "test",
                                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "test")

cursor = connection.cursor()

postgreSQL_select_Query = 'SELECT "CountryDescription" FROM "Countries"'

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

Countries = cursor.fetchall()

for Country in Countries:
    #NOT row[0] instead i like to write Country.CountryDescription
    print("Country = ", row[0], "\n")
```

1. How can I have the record-set in a dataclass?
2. Do I need to move to another package (no problem for me).
3. Maybe this can be solved in psycopg2?

Edit: Thx to Maurice Meyer:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "test",
                                  password = "test",
                                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "test",
                                  cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor)

cursor = connection.cursor()

postgreSQL_select_Query = 'SELECT "CountryDescription" FROM "Countries"'

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

Countries = cursor.fetchall()

for Country in Countries:
    print("Country = ", Country.CountryDescription, "\n")
```

Someone a better solution?

Yours

Comment: You can use namedtuple cursor, as mentioned in the docs: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=range#namedtuple-cursor

Comment: You can use [SQLAlchemy with Postgres.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html)

Comment: :) like I said, I like to write "SELECT * FROM Countries", how can I access with SQL instead of NOSQL in SQLAlchemy? Looks nice, indeed and yes it works with PostgresSQL and psycopg2

Comment: Yes, Thx to @Maurice Meyer, it works!!